# complex ng-if expression not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

lets say I have the following code:

```
<div ng-if="Array.isArray(list)" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
<div ng-if="!Array.isArray(list)"> Not a list </div>
```

The expression alway evalutes as not a list. why?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jlH0z3tLN6qbRowD5NGQ?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the angular docs:

> Context
>
> Angular does not use JavaScript's eval() to evaluate expressions. Instead Angular's $parse service processes these expressions.
>
> Unlike JavaScript, where names default to global window properties, Angular expressions must use $window explicitly to refer to the global window object. For example, if you want to call alert() in an expression you must use $window.alert(). This restriction is intentional. It prevents accidental access to the global state – a common source of subtle bugs.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this more or less:

```
   scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
   //scope.list = 'test';

   scope.isArr = function(arr){
     return Array.isArray(arr);
   }
```

Then:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-show="isArr(list)">{{item}}</div>
  <div ng-show="!isArr(list)">foobarbazz</div>
```

Uncomment the scope.list = 'test' to see the results. This is pretty sloppy, but it gets the point across.

Comment: I know that this would work, but why can't i interpolate the expression directly?

Comment: I got distracted by work. Because you can't do this in expressions. You have to wrap it in your own function.